# How can I control two images with the same button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two images named hungerbar and cheesebar.

when the mouse approaches the cheese one button is activated. and I added pointer down function so when I press cheesebar level is decreasing and when the chees bar is empty the first cheese disappears.

and the second cheese appears but I can not control it with the same code. I dont know how to.

here some samples of my code;

```
void Start()
{
    cheesbar1= GetComponent<Image>();
}

void Update()
{
    cheesbar1.fillAmount = eatencheese / maxcheese;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (eating== true)
    {
        eatencheese--;
        hungerscript.gettinghungery += 3f;
    }
    if (eatencheese <= 0)
        Destruction();
}
```

SO that codes control only one image (Cheesebar1) . I want to use the same code and game object for controlling the second one..

Comment: we need more code/details ... what is `Destruction` doing? where is the new cheese coming from? I don't see nay implementation using pointer down ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this somewhere in your class (preferably at the top)

```
[SerializeField, Tooltip("The image of your second cheesebar")]
private Image cheesebar2;
```

This will add a field that will be exposed to the inspector, like so:

[image: The image of the inspector]

Like what the image states, drag the game-object with the image of the second cheesebar into the new field.

You should be able to modify `cheesebar2` in your code afterwards.

Comment: I have the feeling that OP means it is supposed to be done dynamically on runtime ,,, you don't want to have 300 fields for `cheesbar1` to `cheesbar300` and assign them all via the inspector ... ;) Not your fault though, OP didn't provide enough information to actually provide an answer

Comment: yes I wanted to control all the cheeses with one button that answer given above helped a little bit :) thanks @Kaynn ...now my mouse is happy kkk